# How to properly decompress and view the response obtained from a POST request to a website's API using curl

Tags: curl, request, compression, httpwebresponse

I am attempting to send a POST request to a website's API using the curl command line. I obtained the request headers and body through packet sniffing. After executing the curl command, the response is saved in `output.txt`. However, upon inspection, the file appears in an unexpected format. The response may be compressed using gzip, deflate, or Brotli based on the headers. I have tried using various commands like `brotli`, `inflate`, `zcat`, and `gzip -d` to decompress the file, but none have been successful. How can I correctly decompress and view the response in `output.txt`?

```
url = https://www.my_site.com/api/register

Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Alt-Used: www.my_site.com

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 134

content-type: application/json

Cookie: cf_clearance=uvzZt00yfK5h2O_SEVu2YPNL.5cJT9AnkYJr9YhwhoU-1706709249-1-AUHiOWO+oTJ91OHoTxQWgHVGPNkJF+yqyHbsLFotZWuDb2Uivu/a/ETDZP5fupnkUX6z9mt/+nRhMTEZ7jPmT5c=

Host: www.my_site.com

Origin: https://www.my_site.com

Referer: https://www.my_site.com/?ref=bJsbQYkc

Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty

Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors

Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux aarch64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0

Body:

{"username":"my_phone_no","password":"xGxfUu4ljy9yR8n","captcha":"hF5X","ref":"bJsbQYkc","phone":"my_phone_no","rand":"9142","opt":"hF5X"}
```

```
curl -X POST https://www.my_site.com/api/register \

-H "Accept: */*" \

-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" \

-H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" \

-H "Alt-Used: www.my_site.com" \

-H "Connection: keep-alive" \

-H "Content-Length: 134" \

-H "Content-Type: application/json" \

-H "Cookie: cf_clearance=uvzZt00yfK5h2O_SEVu2YPNL.5cJT9AnkYJr9YhwhoU-1706709249-1-AUHiOWO+oTJ91OHoTxQWgHVGPNkJF+yqyHbsLFotZWuDb2Uivu/a/ETDZP5fupnkUX6z9mt/+nRhMTEZ7jPmT5c=" \

-H "Host: www.supercharles.day" \

-H "Origin: https://www.my_site.com" \

-H "Referer: https://www.my_site.com/?ref=bJsbQYkc" \

-H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty" \

-H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" \

-H "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin" \

-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux aarch64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0" \

-d '{"username":"my_phone_no","password":"xGxfUu4ljy9yR8n","captcha":"hF5X","ref":"bJsbQYkc","phone":"my_phone_no","rand":"9142","opt":"hF5X"}' \

-o output.txt
```

```
┌──(kali㉿localhost)-[~]

└─$ cat output.txt

�#��ړ�Y��>��!S�K�)�*�sQ⚆a)�{��ה��ˑ7���$�|HVJ9.ǫ�p�}9���
```

Below are commands I tried in process of decompressing the file in `output.txt`

```
┌──(kali㉿localhost)-[~]

└─$ brotli -d output.txt

input file [output.txt] suffix mismatch
```

```
┌──(kali㉿localhost)-[~]

└─$ inflate output.txt

Usage: inflate [OPTIONS] START END [AMOUNT]

Try 'inflate --help' for help.

Error: Invalid value for 'START': 'output.txt' is not a valid integer.
```

```
┌──(kali㉿localhost)-[~]

└─$ zcat output.txt

gzip: output.txt: not in gzip format
```

```
┌──(kali㉿localhost)-[~]

└─$ gzip -d output.txt

gzip: output.txt: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the file to indicate Brotli compression:

```
mv output.txt output.txt.br
```

2. Decompress the Brotli file:

```
brotli -d output.txt.br
```

After executing these commands, the decompressed response should be available in the newly created output.txt. This solved the issue for me, and I hope it helps others facing a similar problem.